# Куда знак валюты ставить?

Tags: орфография, порядок-слов, знак

Как в русском правильнее? (Я знаю, что чёткого правила ещё нет.)

1. У меня есть 100$.
2. У меня есть 100 $.
3. У меня есть $100.
4. У меня есть $ 100.

Comment: американцы пишут $100, но 100 €, у нас пишут все после числа - 100$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Четкое правило, конечно же, **у нас** есть.
В справочнике А. Э. Мильчина ([Знаки валют](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82/)):

> Имеющие международное обращение валюты, чьи сокращенные обозначения широко известны ($ — доллар, € — евро), целесообразно употреблять в тексте изданий финансово-экономической литературы, а также изданий других спец. литератур, включающих финансовые расчеты.
> Напр.: Цена 1 кг 7 €; Цена машины 500 000 $.
> В отличие от зарубежной практики, где эти знаки принято ставить перед числом, в наших изданиях, исходя из принятой у нас последовательности чисел и подобных знаков, рекомендуется эти знаки ставить после чисел.

То есть правильно так (число — пробел — знак валюты): **5000 ₽**, **100 ¥**, **20   £**.
И в особых контекстах.